# UILabel auto resize on basis of text to be shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

I'm working on an application, in which I'm required to autoresize the text area on basis of text to be displayed.

Firstly, I'm not sure for this either I should use `UILabel` (Logically is the best choice for displaying static text, which is in my case) or `UITextView`.

**How I wish to use it?**
I want to simply init my Label or text view for that matter with Text.
Instead I define the frame first and then restrict my text in that area.

If you can suggest the right solution, that will be a great help.

I went through documentation and other references but didn't find much which could help me here or I could've overlooked it.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The `sizeToFit` method worked just great.

I did following.

```
UILabel *testLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,3, 262,20 )]; // RectMake(xPos,yPos,Max Width I want, is just a container value);

NSString * test=@"this is test this is test inthis is test ininthis is test inthis is test inthis is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...this is test in uilabel ...";

testLabel.text = test;
testLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //will wrap text in new line
[testLabel sizeToFit];

[self.view addSubview:testLabel];
```

Comment: resized the view horizontally not vertically

Comment: beriks solution resizes vertically properly

Answer (score 29):

You can find a text size with :

```
CGSize textSize = [[myObject getALongText] 
                    sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] 
                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, 2000)
                    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

then you can create your `UILabel` like that :

```
UILabel * lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,textSize.width, textSize.height];
[lbl setNumberOfLines:0];
[lbl setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[lbl setText:[myObject getALongText]];
```

Comment: Wrong: you should not ask the NSString what size it will be when you will draw it inside a UILabel.

Answer (score 15):

In Swift:

```
testLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(6, 3, 262, 20))
testLabel.text = test
testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
testLabel.sizeToFit()
```

In Objective C

```
UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(6, 3, 262, 20)]];
testLabel.text = test;
testLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[testLabel sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to resize the UILabel only in height, use this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

CGRect titleLabelBounds = self.titleLabel.bounds;
titleLabelBounds.size.height = CGFLOAT_MAX;
// Change limitedToNumberOfLines to your preferred limit (0 for no limit)
CGRect minimumTextRect = [self.titleLabel textRectForBounds:titleLabelBounds limitedToNumberOfLines:2];

CGFloat titleLabelHeightDelta = minimumTextRect.size.height - self.titleLabel.frame.size.height;
CGRect titleFrame = self.titleLabel.frame;
titleFrame.size.height += titleLabelHeightDelta;
self.titleLabel.frame = titleFrame;
```

Now you can use `titleLabelHeightDelta` to layout other views depending on your label size (without using autolayout).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but you can use the `sizeToFit` method on a `UILabel` (the method is inherited from `UIView`) to change the size according to the label text.

Comment: @user676298 please mark at least one of the answers as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to find the no. of lines depending on text. You can use this code:

```
ceil(([aText sizeWithFont:aFont].width)/self.bounds.size.width-300);
```

it returns some float value.

```
[lbl setNumberOfLines:floatvalue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that with autolayout call sizeToFit won't change size, because it will be changed later by autolayout calculations. In this case you need to setup proper height constraint for your UILabel with "height >= xx" value.

Comment: This message do provide an answer to the question for modern autolayout technique, just read it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're going to use this solution countless times in your app, do the following:

1) Create a directory called `extensions` and add a new file inside called `UILabel.swift` with the following code:

```
import UIKit

extension UILabel {
    func resizeToText() {
        self.numberOfLines = 0
        self.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

2) In your app code, define the label width you want and just call `resizeToText()`:

```
label.frame.size.width = labelWidth
label.resizeToText()
```

This will maintain width while increasing the height automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try bellow code, it works for multiline

```
self.labelText.text = string;
self.labelText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.labelText.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of label based on length of the string by, using this function

```
func ChangeSizeOfLabel(text:String) -> CGSize{

    let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12)!
    let textAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
    let size = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(310, 999), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textAttributes, context: nil)
    let adjustSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height)
    return adjustSize
}
```

and use it like this :

let

```
showLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width , self.ChangeSizeOfLabel("Hello , Height is changing dynamically.....").height)
```