# How to use autoresizing on UILabel font size

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, autoresize

I use AutoResizing instead of AutoLayout in storyboard . All components will be scaled according to screen size .

But on UILabel , the font size do not change .
I want it scaling in proportion too .
What should I do?

Comment: please refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430890/uilabel-auto-resize-on-basis-of-text-to-be-shown

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `sizeToFit`.`sizeToFit` will change the bounds for the `UILabel` based on it's contents.

```
_yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0; #This will wrap text in new line
[_yourLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: sizeToFit make the view change to fit font size , but I need the opposite .